# Why don't updates to default.hbs show up on the blog?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I've installed Ghost on an Amazon EC2 instance, and it's been working very well so far.

Today I wanted to make some changes in the default.hbs of the theme (I'm using the default casper theme) in order to get code syntax highlighting. (I'm trying to add prism.)
I edited the content/themes/casper/default.hbs file, and added the css and js, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset "css/prism.css"}}" />
```

However, the changes do not show up on my blog.

Then, just to test whether my edits are working, I added some content after the site-wrapper div:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
<h2>Testing editing the default.hbs</h2>
```

However, these changes are not showing up on the blog either. I already tried restarting ghost, and restarting the whole web server.

What can be the problem? Do I have to recompile the site somehow, or erase some cache, etc.?

Comment: My first idea would also be restarting ghost, but since you've already done that I'm not really sure. Have you tried running 'npm install --production' ? And also, how did you restart the server? 'npm stop' and 'npm start --production' should do the trick. Otherwise... I'll try to dig a little bit deeper and se what we can find out :)

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution with trial and error, I'll write up an answer with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hosting my site using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). And the site published with pm2 wasn't updated even if I restarted ghost or restarted the machine.

The site had to be explicitly restarted in pm2 with the following command

```
pm2 restart <app_name>
```

Now my changes properly show up on the site if I restart pm2 every time I want to view my latest changes.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to restart ghost. You can do this using SSH or, more easily, using Softaculous (if thats how you installed ghost) to restart it for you.

Log in to cPanel. In the Software/Services section of the cPanel home screen, click Softaculous. The Softaculous home page appears.
In the icon list at the top right, click the Softaculous - All Installations icon icon (All Installations icon). The list of installed applications appears.
Locate Ghost, and then click the Softaculous - Edit Details icon icon (Edit Details icon).
On the Edit Installation Details page, scroll down to the Node.js Service section.
In the Choose action for Node.js service list box, select the action you want:
(To restart Node.js and Ghost, select Restart.)

If you don't have access to this with your hosting provider you can: 
Log in to your account using SSH.
At the command prompt, type the following command:
pkill node
This command stops Node and takes the Ghost site offline.

Change your current working directory to the directory where you installed Ghost (for example, cd ~/ghost), and then type the following command:

nohup npm start --production &
Ghost should now be running and back online.

This is necessary to see the changes to any file in a ghost theme.

Good luck.

Comment: For ghost 4, ssh to the server, cd to the ghost install directory (usually /var/www/your-ghost-site) and simply `ghost restart`